# Rename certain portion of filepaths in current directory recursively

Tags: bash, find, file-rename

Let's assume I have following directory tree:

```
.
|-- foo
`-- foodir
    |-- bardir
    |   |-- bar
    |   `-- foo
    |-- foo -> bardir/foo
    `-- foodir
        |-- bar
        `-- foo

3 directories, 6 files
```

How can I rename all `foo` into `buz`, including symlinks? like:

```
.
|-- buz
`-- buzdir
    |-- bardir
    |   |-- bar
    |   `-- buz
    |-- buz -> bardir/buz
    `-- buzdir
        |-- bar
        `-- buz

3 directories, 6 files
```

I thought it is relatively easy at the first glance, but it turns out that was unexpectedly tough.

Firstly, I tried to `mv` around all files using `git ls-files`:

```
$ for file in $(git ls-files '*foo*'); do mv "$file" "${file//foo/buz}"; done
```

This gave me a bunch of errors said that I have to create new directories before doing so:

```
mv: cannot move 'foodir/bardir/bar' to 'buzdir/bardir/bar': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'foodir/bardir/foo' to 'buzdir/bardir/buz': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'foodir/foo' to 'buzdir/buz': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'foodir/foodir/bar' to 'buzdir/buzdir/bar': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'foodir/foodir/foo' to 'buzdir/buzdir/buz': No such file or directory
```

I didn't want to care about cleaning up empty directories after copy, so I tried `find -exec` expecting it can handle file renaming while finding files based on its names.

```
$ find . -path .git -prune -o -name '*foo*' -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0//foo/buz}"' "{}" \;
```

But `find` seems still tried renaming files from renamed path.

```
find: ./foodir: No such file or directory
```

My final solution is to `find` the first file/directory for every single `mv` commands.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Rename file paths recursively
while :; do
    path=$(find . -path .git -prune -o -name '*foo*' -print -quit)

    if [ -z "$path" ]; then
        break
    fi

    if ! mv "$path" "${path/foo/buz}"; then
        break
    fi
done

# Change symlink targets as well
find . -path .git -prune -o -type l -exec bash -c '
    target=$(readlink "$0")
    if [ "$target" != "${target//foo/buz}" ]; then
        ln -sfn "${target//foo/buz}"
    fi
' "{}" \;
```

This, kinda lame, but works as I expected.  So my questions are:

1. Can I assume `find` always output directories before its sub directories/files?
2. Is there any chance to avoid using `find` multiple times?

Thank you.